# NameError: name 'process_button16' is not defined

Tags: python, home-automation

I am getting `NameError: name 'process_button16' is not defined` error when running the following code.

It also turns on the LEDs without pushing the button....that shouldn't do that...

I am trying to implement a button press action using an app in [appdaemon](http://appdaemon.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.12/index.html) for [Home Assistant](https://home-assistant.io).  I'm a former developer, but not python so I'm banging my head against the keyboard here....  Any help would be most appreciated.

```
import appdaemon.appapi as appapi
from gpiozero import Button
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

global button    
BUTTON_PIN = 16
button = None



class ButtonSense(appapi.AppDaemon):
    GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(27,GPIO.LOW)

    def initialize(self):
        self.log("-------  Hello -------")
        button = Button(BUTTON_PIN)
        button.when_pressed = process_button16()

    def process_button16():
            GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
            GPIO.output(27,GPIO.HIGH)
            self.log("-------  Pressed -------")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `button.when_pressed = process_button16()` with `button.when_pressed = self.process_button16()`, since you have defined `process_button16()` as a private function of the class `ButtonSense`.

`button.when_pressed = process_button16()` tries to assign a global function named `process_button16()` to `button.when_pressed` and since you have not defined any such **global** function, it throws the error *NameError: name 'process_button16' is not defined*

Comment: That fixed the error, but nothing actually happens now!  See below.

Comment: to work, the code needs to be changed to:
button.when_pressed = self.process_button16
(no parens)